# How to make a Div with a Rails Link clickable?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html, hyperlink

I have a large div:

```
.limeskin:hover {
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
```

that I want to be clickable. Because I'm using Rails I need to have a Rails link be clickable:
For example

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Your Email Address', edit_user_path %>
```

I'm struggling to this.

Here is the whole block:

```
<% @user.posts.each do |post| %>
     <div class="lists">
      <ol class="limeposts">
       <li>
        <div class="limeskin">
          <div class="limebox">
            <div class="limecost">
              <b>Price:</b>
              <%= number_to_currency(post.price, :unit => "R") %><br>
              [...]
<% end %>
```

Any simple legal workable answers?

Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`link_to` can accept a block:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  <div>Hey!</div>
<% end %>
```

This will surround the div with `<a>` tags.

Documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Or if you have a big div and want to make it "clickable", using jQuery:

```
# html.erb
<div class="limeskin">
  <div class="limebox">
    <div class="limecost">
      <b>Price:</b>
      <%= number_to_currency(post.price, :unit => "R") %><br>
      #[...]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

# jQuery.js
$('.limeskin').click( function(event) {
  var clicked_div = $(this);
  # do stuff with the event object and 'this' which 
  # represent the element you just clicked on
});
```

## jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lxw34w5o/1/

Comment: Hi thanks, it makes the limeface and limcost div content clickable, but nothing else. I want the whole block (see style sheet added) for limeskin to be clickable.

Comment: Okay give me a sec I'll post a solution with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript (I recommend jQuery) to make the action actually happen and CSS `hover` selector to modify the div background and the cursor (to change the cursor from an arrow to a hand).

Answer (score 1):

Using Link_to as below would be sufficient even when you have a big block including multiple tags:

```
<%= link_to desired_path do %>
    <div class="linkable">
        <another div>
             ... some other tags
        </another div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

and I recommend you to use a different background color for mouse over events because it shows the viewer that it's a link!

In you .css file:

```
.linkable:hover{
    background-color: red;

}
```

Comment: When I do this in my index.html.erb file the row actually just doesn't display at all. Do you know what could cause that?

Comment: @AbbeyJackson Check your code and be sure to use <%= not <%

Comment: Yes I copied it directly from here to be sure

Comment: @AbbeyJackson Check your code and mostly your CSS. Check it without the link_to and also use Inspect Element in your browser to see what is happening.