# Rails how to use link_to for an external website and also using a block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, erb, link-to

I am trying to use link_to with block and also to link with an external web site, I already know how to use link_to to make my div clickable [(learned from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304407/how-to-make-a-div-with-a-rails-link-clickable) and also to use link_to to send user to another website [(learned from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721816/how-do-i-defined-a-variable-link-to-to-an-external-url) but when I try to combine this two approches I got an error:

`undefined method 'stringify_keys' for "www.google.com":String`

Here is my html.erb code:

```
<%= link_to @slides[0].link, "#{@slides[0].link}", target: "_blank"  do %>
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <%= image_tag @slides[0].slide_image.thumb.url, class: "d-block w-100", alt: @slides[0].image_text %>
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h5><%= @slides[0].image_text %></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I also tried:

```
<%= link_to @slides[0].link do %> # or
<%= link_to "#{@slides[0].link}", :target => "_blank" do %>
# I got the same error

<%= link_to url_for(@slides[0].link) do %>
# above I got localhost:3000/https://google.com insted of https://google.com
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `link_to` with block works like this:

```
link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # block
end
```

[link_to helper source](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

So you just have to do :

```
<%= link_to @slides[0].link, target: "_blank"  do %>
  #block
<% end %>
```

(assuming `@slides[0].link == "https://google.com"` i.e valid external url)