# How to create a file on users machine instead of creating in server and then to download using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on to allow download an excel file with the below code:

```
login     = Etc.getlogin
@dataFile = "C:/rails/#{login}data.csv"

csv1=CSV.open(@dataFile, 'w') do |csv|
  $data.each do |eachrow|
    csv << [eachrow.name+"@gmail.com"]
  end
end

send_file(@dataFile, :filename => "#{login}data", :type =>  "application/csv")
```

Using the above code, I am able to create a file and write the data.

Instead of this, how do i write the data in csv and get downloaded into users machine instead of saving in local/server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is generate a string with the CSV library, using [`CSV::generate`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate) instead of [`CSV::open`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open).

Controller:

```
class DataController < ApplicationController
  def download
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv { send_csv_download }
    end
  end

  private

  def send_csv_download
    string = CSV.generate do |csv|
      @data.each { |row| csv << ["#{row.name}@gmail.com"] }
    end

    send_data string, filename: 'foo.csv', type: :csv
  end

end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
get '/download', to: 'data#download'
```

View:

```
<%= link_to 'Download CSV', download_path(format: :csv) %>
```

**Note:** Obviously, I have no idea where you get your `@data` from, since it isn't specified in your question.

Comment: Tried with the above code, but still the file is not getting downloaded.

Comment: @MallelaSriPrakash any errors? I tried it in rails 5.1.5 and it worked.

Comment: @Mark First we use CSV's `generate` method to make string that represents the comma-separated data. Then it is wrapped in a I/O stream object to be able to send it to the client. But now as I am writing this I think we can drop the StringIO and just send the string itself.

Comment: I dont see any file being downloaded. 
I am having ajax call on button click which calls the method from the controller.
But, per this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304407/how-to-make-a-div-with-a-rails-link-clickable it seems to be it wont work with ajax calls

Comment: @MallelaSriPrakash Well, you should've mentioned the AJAX call in your question. As it is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242359/how-to-trigger-download-with-rails-send-data-from-ajax-post/17526267 you might try rendering a partial that will download a file for you. But I would just do it without AJAX.

Comment: @mityakoval, apologies for not mentioning the same. Can you help me the sample code without ajax or by using <a href as suggested for achieving the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MallelaSriPrakash I've updated the answer. Obviously, I have no idea where you get your `@data` from.

Comment: @mityakoval, Really thanks for the above sample code. That worked.

Comment: @mityakoval, sorry to bother you again. Can you tell me what is download_path(format: :csv) in the above code.
Being novice, thought to clear the doubt

Comment: @MallelaSriPrakash That will translate to the string `'/download.csv'`. The `download_path` helper is generated by setting the route `get '/download', to: 'data#download'`. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html